# Trouble with three layered nested quotes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, escaping, quotes

Here is my situation. I have a rails view with a javascript function on the page. Inside that function, I am using a snippet of erb which needs to output a string to that function. The variable I am using in the erb contains a string of html. This html string has strings inside of it for the various element attributes. And finally some of the strings for the element attributes has strings as well due to css.

This is what my javascript function looks like:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<%= @template.html_safe %>');
```

And this is what it looks like after the erb gets rendered:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<table border="0" class="mceItemTable" width="440" style="height: 309px; "><tbody><tr><td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff0000;" data-mce-style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff0000;"><span style="font-size: xx-large; font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; color: rgb(255, 255, 0); ">THIS</span></td><td style="background-color: rgb(154, 205, 50); text-align: center; "><span style="font-size: xx-large; font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; color: rgb(30, 144, 255); ">IS</span></td></tr><tr><td style="background-color: rgb(30, 144, 255); text-align: center; "><span style="font-size: xx-large; font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; color: rgb(154, 205, 50); ">A</span></td><td style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0); text-align: center; "><span style="font-size: xx-large; font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); ">TEST</span></td></tr></tbody></table><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>');
```

This doesn't cause any problems up until a situation like this comes up:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span style="font-family: 'arial black', 'avant garde'; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); ">TEST</span>');
```

I need to escape the inner most level quotes so they don't conflict with the outer quotes.

Comment: and using the `\\ ` escape character didn't work? (`\'` where `'` was used)

Answer (score 2):

There's a helper for this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<%= escape_javascript @template %>')
```

It's also aliased to `j`

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of a very simple solution that looks like it works. I just replaced the occurrences of ' with `&quot;`

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<%= @template.gsub(/'/, "&quot;").html_safe %>');
```